# chrony on AlmaLinux 8.6 using unspecified servers [SOLVED]

Tags: chrony

So I have two (virtual) servers running a fully updated AlmaLinux 8.6.  I noticed that regardless of what I put for 'server' or 'pool' entries, chrony seems to insist on also using any DNS servers.  I hadn't noticed this before, since my 2 win 2019 DC act as DNS as well as NTP.  I am playing with freeipa, and wanted a couple of test VM running a (basically) CentOS 8 install.  Here is the line in /etc/chrony.conf:

server 10.0.0.4 iburst

## chronyc sources
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample

^* 10.0.0.4                      3   6   377    21  +9586ns[  -29us] +/-   56ms
^? 10.0.0.22                     0   8     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 10.0.0.23                     0   8     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns

I've googled high and low and found nothing useful.  My 2 CentOS 7 VMs work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

might you have the following lines in chrony.conf?

```
# Use NTP servers from DHCP.
sourcedir /run/chrony-dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be picking up NTP servers from DHCP offer. Do you use DHCP for IP autoconfiguration?

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks!  My current DCs are DNS *and* NTP, and I cut and pasted in the two new DNS resolvers.  This never occurred to me, since I wasn't aware of chrony looking at DHCP (NB: I did NOT have the sourcedir command referenced, so it must be doing that by default?)

Comment: Yes, it is `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/20-chrony-dhcp` script doing that and it is a part of `chrony` rpm package.

Comment: Thanks, Tomek.  This was in fact the issue.